# Issue with C# TCP Client not able to send messages after disconnecting and reconnecting

Tags: c#, .net, tcp

I'm having an issue where my TCP Listener doesn't receive any data after a client connects and reconnects. I'm fairly new to TCP/IP so I'm sure it's just a concept I don't understand or logic error. There aren't any errors in the logs or obvious issues (to me).

**Client Code**

```
/// <summary>
/// Class for sending data over TCP
/// </summary>
public class TcpMessageSender : MessageSender
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Udp Client that sends messages
    /// </summary>
    public TcpClient TcpClient { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor which initializes the client
    /// </summary>
    public TcpMessageSender(string ipAddress, int port)
    {
        ConnectToAddress(ipAddress, port);
        TcpClient = new TcpClient();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor which initializes the client
    /// </summary>
    public TcpMessageSender(IPAddress ipAddress, int port)
    {
        ConnectToAddress(ipAddress, port);
        TcpClient = new TcpClient();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor
    /// </summary>
    public TcpMessageSender()
    {
        TcpClient = new TcpClient();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sends data over a network stream using the client
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data"></param>
    public override void SendMessage(byte[] data)
    {
        NetworkStream nwStream = TcpClient.GetStream();

        if(nwStream != null)
        {
            nwStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Connects the Tcp client to the end point
    /// </summary>
    public void Connect()
    {
        TcpClient.Connect(IPEndPoint);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Closes the connection
    /// </summary>
    public override void CloseConnection()
    {
        TcpClient.Close();
    }
}
```

**Server Code**

```
public class TcpMessageReceiver : MessageReceiver
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Listener for getting values
    /// </summary>
    public TcpListener TcpListener { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Call back for receiving data
    /// </summary>
    public Action<string> OnReceivedData;

    /// <summary>
    /// Message callback from the thread
    /// </summary>
    public string MessageData { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Listen thread reference
    /// </summary>
    private Thread m_ListenThread;

    /// <summary>
    /// Flag to tell the thread to stop
    /// </summary>
    private bool m_KillThread_Flag = false;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor for setting up a new listener
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="address">IP Address</param>
    /// <param name="port">Port</param>
    public TcpMessageReceiver(IPAddress address, int port)
    {
        ConnectToAddress(address, port);
        TcpListener = new TcpListener(IPEndPoint);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor for setting up a new listener
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="address">IP Address</param>
    /// <param name="port">Port</param>
    public TcpMessageReceiver(string address, int port)
    {
        ConnectToAddress(address, port);
        TcpListener = new TcpListener(IPEndPoint);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the listening thread
    /// </summary>
    public void StartListening()
    {
        m_KillThread_Flag = false;
        ThreadStart childref = new ThreadStart(ListenThread);
        m_ListenThread = new Thread(childref);
        m_ListenThread.Start();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Kills the listen thread and stops the TCP Listener
    /// </summary>
    public void StopListening()
    {
        m_KillThread_Flag = true;
        TcpListener.Stop();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Thread for listening for incomign data
    /// </summary>
    private void ListenThread()
    {
        TcpListener.Start();
        TcpClient client = TcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

        while (!m_KillThread_Flag)
        {
            try
            {
                if (client.GetStream() != null)
                {
                    NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();

                    if (nwStream.DataAvailable)
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];

                        //---read incoming stream---
                        int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);

                        //---convert the data received into a string---
                        string dataReceived = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                        if (OnReceivedData != null)
                        {
                            OnReceivedData.Invoke(dataReceived);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageData = e.Message;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Tells the listener to stop
    /// </summary>
    public override void CloseConnection()
    {
        StopListening();
    }
}
```

For compatibility reasons I need to try to stick .NET 3.5. There is some room for upgrading if necessary though. If there is anything super obvious about the code I would definitely appreciate it being pointed out to me.

But just to clarify. The issue I'm having is if I start up the server, and then start the client. They interact fine. If I disconnect the client and then reconnect it, the server will not receive data from that client. I'm not sure if this is just an issue of trying to run both the server and client on the same machine or not. But any help would definitely be appreciated!

Comment: Is `StopListening()` in the server called when you close the first client?

Comment: Be aware that TCP is *an endless stream of bytes in both directions*. Not messages. There's no guarantee that a single call to `Write` at one end will be matched 1-1 with a single call to `Read` at the other end. If you want *messaging*, it's up to *you* to implement message framing (by e.g. prefixing your actual messages by the message length, using fixed length messages or having a delimiter byte), or to move to a higher level protocol that does this for you. Your server only calls `AcceptTcpClient` once so you can only connect once.